# How to import Cordova Plugin (IndoorAtlasSDK) into Ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to import and use the Cordova Plugin IndoorAtlas SDK into an Ionic Project. I tried different Tutorials/AnswerForums from all over the Internet but none of them worked. So that's why I'm asking here. The Ionic Project is using Angular.

I have already set up an Ionic Cordova Angular Project and imported the IndoorAtlas plugin using the following code:

```
cordova plugin add "path"
```

Is this correct this way? I also read somewhere that I have to create a wrapper to use the plugin?
How can I start using the plugin in my Project?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Folder structure Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community) to get a nicer Typescript API if the plugin is implemented. But as you said this is just a wrapper library. You can always use the JavaScript functions from the plugin in your Ionic app.

Comment: I tried to import a JS File from the plugin with `import * as IndoorAtlas from 'plugins/Cordova-plugin-indooratlas/www/IndoorAtlas.js';` but I can't access any of the methods in the app.module.ts file. Did I forget something to import the Js File correctly?